# Failed to compare php returned value in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have problem with Ajax / PHP.

Example:

My Jquery

```
//LOGIN-----------------------------

$('#login').click(function() {

$username = $('#username').val();
$password = $('#password').val();

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../php/ajax.php",
  data: {
        action: "login", 
        username: $username, 
        password: $password
        },
  success: function(data)
  {
    if (data === 'login') {
        window.location = '../www/master.php';
    }
    else {
        alert(data);
    }
  }
  });
});
```

This is a part of my recieving PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'login':
            if($db->Login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
                echo 'login';
            }
            break;
   }
}
```

When im trying to login the alert gives me "login" in the popup. So it seems like everything works and the PHP is sending "login" back to the Ajax, but instead of accepting it and redirect the user, it thinks something is wrong and runs the else -statement instead.

By the way, the connection works, when i tried to INSERT in the query instead, the records is showing in the DB, the issue from the Ajax still was there though.

Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Comment: try to see what is inside the `data` after ajax success on console like this `console.log(data)` before doing any kind of conditional checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably whitespace around the AJAX response. try trimming the string before comparing:

```
if (data.trim() == "login")
```

Comment: I tried to log the response, the type was String and the value was 'login'. Once i trimmed the string it seems to be working as it should. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade the [strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) operator `===` to a standard `==` operator.

You should check the type of the data you are returning back:

```
console.log(typeof data);
```

And use strict comparison  operator only *after* you are sure about the kind of data you are handling.

Comment: How would this help? `==` is for automatically converting types, but `data` is always going to be a string.

Comment: What other type of data would look like `login` when he alerts it?